# Capture audio from single application

Tags: windows-7, audio, capture

I need to capture/record audio of a single application. Other applications, with sounds, may run simultaneously, but I only want the output of a single one. The microphone needs to work while doing this as well (though it's not the microphones output I want). The captured audio should preferably be written to wave file continuously.

I'm running Win 7 x64. I've noticed that the application "Livestream Producer" seems to be able to grab the output of games, so I guess it should be possible somehow.

For Mac OS X, there seems to be programs which accomplish this, like "WireTap", "SoundFlower" and "Audio Hijack".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Total Recorder](http://www.totalrecorder.com/)?  It is able to record any audio on your machine, not quite sure if it can pick the source though.

Comment: I didn't find a way to select a specific program.